# There is GPG error when I use MongoDB 4.4

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, apt-get

I am very new about MongoDB, And I want to use MongoDB 4.4 Version on Ubuntu 18.04. So I installed it.
But, some GPG error comes up when I use `sudo apt-get update`.
It is about 4.0 version.

```
Ign:2 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.0 InRelease
Ign:3 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.4 InRelease
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:6 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.0 Release [2,989 B]
Hit:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:8 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.4 Release
Hit:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Get:11 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.0 Release.gpg [801 B]
Ign:11 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.0 Release.gpg
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.0 Release: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 68818C72E52529D4 MongoDB 4.0 Release Signing Key <packaging@mongodb.com>
E: The repository 'https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.0 Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I don't know why these error comes up despite i installed 4.4 version.

Here is the proof that I installed only 4.4 version.
[image: I typed apt list --installed | grep mongodb]

Comment: You can bypass this by  `sudo apt update --allow-insecure-repositories` --  I would look into the security aspect of allowing repos from unsecure sources ..  But this work around `--allow-insecure-repositories` should allow you to install

Comment: What is the question? Can you use the version of mongodb that you installed or not?

Comment: I Can use MongoDB that I install but, those error message is popped up, even I didn't install 4.0 version.